# How to Parse / substitute value in jq for json file

Tags: json, jq

How to parse / substitute value in jquery.

Json file as below:

```
{
  "09800214851900C3": {
    "label": "P7-R1-R16:S2",
    "name": "Geist Upgradable rPDU",
    "state": "normal",
    "order": 0,
    "type": "i03",
    "snmpInstance": 1,
    "lifetimeEnergy": "20155338",
    "outlet": {},
    "alarm": {
      "severity": "",
      "state": "none"
    },
    "layout": {
      "0": [
        "entity/total0",
        "entity/phase0",
        "entity/phase1",
        "entity/phase2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to do like below, But this is not working. Any idea/leads on this will be appreciated.

```
a=09800214851900C3

jsonfile.json | jq '.${a}.label'
```

Comment: `jq` is not shorthand for `jQuery`

Comment: @Taplar do you happen to know what it's short for, if anything? I searched but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't know that it is short for anything.  You can click the tag and go to the "Learn More" section to read up on it.  @Aaron

Comment: jq is technically just a name, but it's evidently inspired by the words "JSON Query" -- compare SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current try has the following problems :

- `jsonfile.json` isn't a command, so you can't use it as the first token of a command line. You could `cat jsonfile.json | jq ...`, but the prefered way to have `jq` work on a file is to use `jq 'command' file`
- you define a variable `a` in your shell, but you try to reference it inside a single-quoted string, which prevents the shell from expanding it to its actual value. A shell based solution is to use double-quotes to have the variable expanded, but it's preferable to define the variable in the context of `jq` itself, using a `--arg varname value` option
- `09800214851900C3` isn't considered a "simple, identifier-like key" by `jq` (because it starts with a digit), so the standard way of accessing the value associated to this key (`.key`) doesn't work and you need to use `."09800214851900C3"` or `.["09800214851900C3"]` instead

In conclusion I believe you will want to use the following command :

```
jq --arg a 09800214851900C3 '.[$a].label' jsonfile.json
```